# MongoDB Relational Property Updates

Tags: mongodb, data-structures, database-design, architecture, foreign-keys

I have two collections named `"Books"` and `"Authors"`. In addition in books collection there is a sub document named `Author` as shown below

```
[{
  "Id" : "3535345345",
  "Title" : "Book Name",
  "Published" : "2015-02-20",
  "Author" : {
    "Id" : "344567656",
    "FirstName" : "Alex",
    "LastName" : "Tyler"
  }
},
{
  "Id" : "3535967667",
  "Title" : "Another Book",
  "Published" : "2016-08-12",
  "Author" : {
    "Id" : "344567656",
    "FirstName" : "Alex",
    "LastName" : "Tyler"
  }
}]
```

As you see `"Author"` document is duplicated in documents to make queries faster / better. As I mentioned before Authors are recorded in another collection and hust 3 columns of Authors is included to Books.

First question is : "Is that structure true for MongoDB?"

Second question is :  "What is the best practise when I updated an author's LastName? What should I do to updated realtional places like in Books." I tried to updated by referencing Id from Author collection but in big data scenarios I thought i is not the best choice.

Thanks

Comment: How can author being duplicated in documents make queries faster/better?

Comment: What I feel is that you don't need two collections. Since MongoDB is all about being schema-less, why don't you store Author as a single, unique document in Books collection itself, with all the ids of the books it is referenced by inside an array as one of the key-value pairs of Author document? Even the queries would be simpler.

Comment: I will answer your questions by giving samples. First one : Querying book name and author firstname and lastname from one document is better or faster then asking another collection by objectid of author. You can imagine INNER JOIN queries in MSSQL Server or other RDBMS. Second one : In our scenario it is impossible but what if an author has 100K books? There is a possibility exceeding the mongoDB document limits

Comment: In real world No Author can have 100k books

Comment: So I hope my second comment was what you're telling me now. Lemme tell you something else... You cannot say yes to redundancy for efficiency and talk about big data at the same time, bruh.

Comment: I know but you should read carefully. I wrote : "In our scenario it is impossible but ..." please focus on technologic idea.

Comment: Whoa. Did you read my comment properly as I was not referring to that comment of yours? I was still answering your question as an extension to my second comment.

Comment: :) I answered @Shubham sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: I wanna ask about your second comment @AakashVerma. I can put Author into Book directly. But when I want to get Authors as an array what should I do? Querying Books.Author and distinct?

Comment: Easy. Now for all the books belonging to one author there will be one document for that author. So we will have distinct author documents in the collection. Now store these author documents with object Id having some common nomenclature like AUTH3263354gr. Get the list of all authors using `db.collection.find({_id:/^AUTH/});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to store in the `Books` collection the `Authors`'s _id.

If you want to populate the `Authors` field you can use `$lookup` aggregation on `Books` collection like this:

```
db.Books.aggregate({
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "Authors",//Author collection
       localField: "AuthorId",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "Author"
     }
})
```

You can check more about `$lookup` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

`AuthorId` field on `Books` collection should be `ObjectId`!

You can also build a view over `Books` collection with `Author` field populated (only available for Mongo 3.4+):

```
db.createView("Books_View", "Books", [{       
     $lookup: {
             from: "Authors",//Authors collection
             localField: "AuthorId",
             foreignField: "_id",
             as: "Author"
         }
    }
])
```

After you can query this view like any other collection:

```
db.Books_View.find({...})
```

Comment: It is an option to solve my problem but it is not the best way. Because in my real scenario there are many parent objects (Author) and aggregating them may be cost much. Thanks in advence

Comment: I've done something like this on a collection with ~ 2 mil entries. I don't think it will move slow since you are aggregating on an indexed field.